# MongoDB aggregation based on user object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

I've been developing a full stack application for personal use and I am starting to learn MongoDB. I'm not really understanding how aggregation functions work and I could use some help.

This is what my data looks like:

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"60a55de5c6006332a883ffc8"
   },
   "date":{
      "$date":"2021-05-19T18:49:15.504Z"
   },
   "user":"Bob",
   "movies":[
      {
         "genre":[
            28,
            80,
            18,
            53
         ],
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"60a55b737098830015d15238"
         },
         "id":1621449587465,
         "title":"Heat",
         "poster":"/obpPQskaVpSiC9RcJRB6iWDTCXS.jpg",
         "release":"1995-12-15",
         "ranking":3
      },
      {
         "genre":[
            28,
            878,
            18
         ],
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"60a55b777098830015d15239"
         },
         "id":1621449591251,
         "title":"Snowpiercer",
         "poster":"/nzccOvhrLGI0nvAknCEAk8bchD9.jpg",
         "release":"2013-08-01",
         "ranking":2
      },
      {
         "genre":[
            18,
            80
         ],
         "_id":{
            "$oid":"60a55b7b7098830015d1523a"
         },
         "id":1621449595243,
         "title":"The Shawshank Redemption",
         "poster":"/q6y0Go1tsGEsmtFryDOJo3dEmqu.jpg",
         "release":"1994-09-23",
         "ranking":1
      }
   ],
   "__v":0
}
```

There are going to be multiple of these objects with the same user and I want to combine all of the objects based on the user value. I thought I would have to use `$group` but that doesn't seem to work.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Or even if can be combined based on the date that would be fine!

Comment: Please add the expected output and the query you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

pls find sample here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3BWUuwSNFCV

go through documentation for more details:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "Data": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Above sample is grouping records based on user and pushing all data in array inside data attribute. but you can do so many things in aggregation like selecting first matched attribute, or sum, or addtoset & so on based on your need to get data back from DB.